# Erlang: List Comprehension, lists:map/2, lists:foreach/2 To use

Tags: erlang

The effect between List Comprehension and lists:map/2, the latter's performance seem better form my testing.

Ref link about List Comprehension from Efficiency Guide
User's Guide : http://www.erlang.org/doc/efficiency_guide/listHandling.html#id66810

It said "**if the result of the list comprehension will obviously not be used, a list will not be constructed.**"

**Question**: I wonder if lists:map/2 's result without using(like lists:foreach/2), would it be the same as list comprehension that **"a list will not be constructed"** ??

Comment: First, why are you writing code such that you can't tell whether you're using the result of a call to `lists:map/2` or not? And second, my opinion is that your focus on such micro-optimization is misplaced.

Comment: @SteveVinoski This touches on a point of ambiguity I've always wanted to address -- the difference between iterating over a list in some way specifically for the side-effects of doing so, as opposed to receiving a return value. If we had a lists:map or a different form of list comprehension meant for side effects instead of "value building, or maybe side-effects" then `ok | {error, {Index, Reason}}` could be the appropriate return type, not a list that isn't used, so we could use assertion-or-error type code instead of leaving this case ambiguous.

Comment: How would the compiler or runtime know whether or not side-effects were occurring in such a call?

Comment: @SteveVinoski , I know how to use them, I just read the Efficiency Guide User's Guide and came up with this question.

Comment: @SteveVinoski The for-the-side-effects map/comprehension would have to be a different function than lists:map or a normal comprehension. Something like a `lists:smap/2` or a deliberately different brace style for a list comprehension -- or both. They shouldn't be subtly overloaded versions of the same function we expect the compiler to detect. This case should have an explicit outlet instead of an implicit optimization as list comprehensions currently do.

Comment: @zxq9 Even if you make it a different function or change the syntax, neither the compiler nor the runtime, in anything like their present forms, could enforce a lack of side effects without resorting to restrictions like those currently imposed for guards.

Comment: `lists:foreach/2` for side-effects as it never builds the value list and returns `ok`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lists:map/2` is a function which is already compiled in your system, in fact the main point is that **it is compiled in a separate module that your code**, so the compiler must not make any assumption about the usage or not of the results. list comprehension is compiled within your code, so it is possible to perform optimization

**[edit]**  sorry, I didn't re-check, lists:map is written:

```
map(F, [H|T]) ->
    [F(H)|map(F, T)];
map(F, []) when is_function(F, 1) -> [].
```

**not a list comprehension!**

Comment: **the funny thing is that lists:map/2 uses list comprehension**, I've had such this guess, but when I did a comparing test, it seem list comprehension cost more time???

Answer (score 2):

One way to check this is to write a function that uses `lists:map/2` in a way that's clearly useless, and then trace it. Consider this function:

```
map() ->
    dbg:tracer(), dbg:p(self(), call),
    dbg:tpl(lists,map,c),
    lists:map(fun(X) -> X end, []),
    dbg:stop_clear().
```

If you implement this function in module `x`, compile it, then spawn a call to it in the shell (the spawn eliminates trace messages caused by the shell itself), you see something like the following:

```
3> spawn(x,map,[]).
<0.45.0>
(<0.45.0>) call lists:map(#Fun<dbg.2.121426812>,[]) ({lists,map,2})
(<0.45.0>) call lists:map(#Fun<x.0.133743400>,[]) ({x,map,0})
(<0.45.0>) call lists:map(#Fun<dbg.2.121426812>,[nonode@nohost]) ({dbg,
                                                                   do_ctp,2})
(<0.45.0>) call lists:map(#Fun<dbg.2.121426812>,[]) ({lists,map,2})
(<0.45.0>) call lists:map(#Fun<dbg.2.121426812>,[nonode@nohost]) ({dbg,
                                                                   do_ctp,2})
```

As you can see from the third line of trace output, the anonymous function `#Fun<x.0.133743400>` was called, which is the anonymous function inside our `x:map/0` function, and the caller was `{x,map,0}`, better known as `x:map/0`. (All the other trace messages were caused by calls from the `dbg` module, which I used for tracing.)

Another approach is to compile to assembly using the `-S` option of the `erlc` compiler. First eliminate the `dbg` calls:

```
map() ->
    lists:map(fun(X) -> X end, []).
```

Then compile with `-S` and look at the result:

```
{function, map, 0, 4}.
  {label,3}.
    {line,[{location,"x.erl",8}]}.
    {func_info,{atom,x},{atom,map},0}.
  {label,4}.
    {make_fun2,{f,15},0,0,0}.
    {move,nil,{x,1}}.
    {line,[{location,"x.erl",9}]}.
    {call_ext_only,2,{extfunc,lists,map,2}}.
```

The important lines here are the third from last, `{move,nil,{x,1}}.`, which moves an empty list into a VM register to be passed as an argument, and the final line, which is the call to `lists:map/2`.

Based on these results, which were constructed using Erlang 17.4, it's safe to say that the answer to your question is no.